# keep getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'publicUsername' of null" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

hey guys i have a function that validate a form before submitting into the database,however one of the field need to be unique so i have to send the data back to database to do comparison and if there's an error it will indicate user, else it will save the data into database. but i keep getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'publicUsername' of null" and i don't know why

#### my code

```
  this.handleSignup = function(req, res, next) {
        "use strict";
    var validate = validateSignup(req.body, function(error, data) {
        if(error) {
            res.send(400, error.message);
        } 
    });
    if(validate){
            users.addUser(data, function(err, user) {
                sessions.startSession(data, function(err, session_id) {
                    "use strict";
                    if (err) return next(err);
                    res.cookie('session', session_id);
                    res.send(200);
                });
            });   
    }
}
```

#### validateSignup

```
function validateSignup(data,callback) {
    "use strict";
  users.checkPublicUsername(data.publicUsername, function(err, result){
      if(result){
       callback(new Error('Public Username is taken Please choose another'), null);
             }
        });
```

#### checkPublicUsername

```
  this.checkPublicUsername = function(data,callback) {
        var publicUsername = {
            "publicUsername":data
        }
        users.findOne(publicUsername, function(err, result) { 
             if(result.publicUsername === data){//terminal show this line is the error
                callback(null,true); // if match return true to trigger indicator
             }else{
                callback(null,false); // else return false to proceed
             }
        })

    }
```

Comment: The error is supposed to give you the exact file and line number. What else do you need?

Comment: yea i know , but i don't get it why i keep getting it

Comment: What is the function user.findOne? because the result being passed into the callback is null.

Comment: @TheThirdOne this function is to compare existed data with publicUsername, if the data match(which mean it can't be used because it has to be unique)

Comment: I guessed that. But the error is somewhere in that function so if you want help you'll have to show it.

Comment: assuming that you use mongoose, the request returns no result (that is, `null`). Anyway, you are first searching for doc with `publicUsername === data` and then just want to make sure it worked?

Comment: @vkurchatkin sorry what do you mean by and then just want to make sure it worked?

Comment: @JohnLim `result.publicUsername === data` - this line, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @vkurchatkin i'm trying to compare the result with the data user key-in , because it has to be unique so i have to validate it before i insert in into database

Comment: @JohnLim but you already made a query with `{"publicUsername":data}`

Comment: @vkurchatkin yes, but the returned result is bunch of data, i only need the publicUsername to compare with data that's why i use result.publicUsername to compare with data key-in by user

Comment: With this few information i can only say that the problems seems that comes from that req.body is null. What is strange as if it not properly set, usually in the html form, it should be undefined or a {}. A quick search in google have brought me to here http://rizsharif.blogspot.com.es/2012/04/nodejs-express-requestbody-is-null.html . Maybe is your same situation ?

Comment: @user688877 hey thanks for your reply , but i don't think we have the same situation

Comment: You are using findOne so if there is no document with that query it will return null after that you are trying to check result.publicUserName.Since result is null you cannot get it is property. You should check if result is null or not.

Comment: what am i trying to do is to compare the data key-in by user with the existed data in my database,if the data key-in by user is existed then return true to trigger the indicator else let the form submit, but this is what i have so far

Comment: This code has many errors, not just one. Insert some `console.log()` calls and see until where your code runs. And show us the route-registration. I suppose your calling the route-handler with GET and req.body is null. Then the TypeError is thrown in the first statement of `validateSignup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call:

```
    users.findOne( { "publicUsername" : data } )
```

If it returns anything that means the publicUsername they tried to use already exists.  If findOne returns null that means it does not yet exist.   You should not be doing further checks of the returned document - the fact that it was returned means it matched your query and publicUsername is guaranteed to be equal to data.   When it didn't exist null was returned and that's all you need to know.

Another way of doing the exact same thing would be to call the `count()` function for
 `{ "publicUsername" : data }` and to interpret 1 to be "it's taken" and 0 to be "it's available".

Please note that this is not sufficient checking - between the time you checked the database and the time you send the user's new registration to the back end, someone else could have taken that username, so you must have a [unique index on publicUsername](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/) to prevent duplicate insertions and you should catch the duplicate error and handle it in your application as well.